# Is this an unexpected keyword

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I'm inside of a ColdFusion custom tag, and this line

```
20 :    param attributes.name       = "";
21 :    param attributes.id         = attributes.name;
22 :    param attributes.inline     false;
23 :    param attributes.look       = "";
24 :    param attributes.processed  = true;
```

**Update**

This is OK

```
22 :    if(!structKeyExists(attributes, "inline"))  attributes["inline"]    =   false;
```

Gets an error

> You cannot use a variable reference with "." operators in this context
>
> The CFML compiler was processing:
>
> ```
> A script statement beginning with param on line 22, column 9.
> A script statement beginning with { on line 12, column 36.
> A script statement beginning with switch on line 12, column 1.
> A cfscript tag beginning on line 6, column 2.
> ```

Is this a keyword? If so what is it?

Comment: Wouldn't the syntax be param name="attributes.name" default=""; ?

Comment: 'param attributes.inline     false;' You have missed equal to (=) operator.

Comment: I think the error message mislead me.

Comment: Yes, hate it when that happens.  Important lesson of the day: sometimes error messages lie ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed equal to (=) operator on line 22.

Instead of

```
 param attributes.inline     false;
```

Write

```
 param attributes.inline   =  false;
```